# Standard F* keys need holding Fn key on Compaq CQ62

Tags: keyboard, compaq-laptop

I got a Compaq CQ62 laptop recently. I find that I have to hold down the Fn keys to use the standard F* keys while accessing the special functionalities like media keys does not.

This is frustrating as the standard keys are used more often the special functions. Is there anyway to fix it so that it behaves like other sane laptops out there?

I use Ubuntu Lucid, but this behavior is present on laptops running Windows 7 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an HP G72 ( HP G72-250us to be precise) laptop.  I have the same problem.  I have to hold down the function Fn key along with the F* keys in order to get "standard functionatliy."

[To get into the BIOS](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02035108&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN), I pressed `Esc` or `F10` during startup. The BIOS software for this HP model is called *InsydeH20*.  At the *System Configuration* menu option, navigate to *Action Keys* and select *Disable* if you want to not have to press the `Fn` key to get standard use out of the function keys.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for that laptop in particular, but my HP laptop was the same.

Have a look in the BIOS so something labelled Enhanced Function keys, or anything else about the function keys and toggle that setting.

Use my advice at your own risk obviously, but that's where the setting will be.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm a CQ62 user as well. When starting your lappy, during the orange screen go into the BIOS setup and you can change your settings over there. :D