# Windows: Using the fn key as a toggle, rather than holding it

Tags: keyboard, fn-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard F* keys need holding Fn key on Compaq CQ62](https://superuser.com/questions/128291/standard-f-keys-need-holding-fn-key-on-compaq-cq62)

I've got an HP dv6t-6100 with the fn key functioning so that by default, the F keys change the volume, brightness, etc. When I press the fn key and hold it, I can use the F1-12 keys like normal.

Is there any way to use the fn button similarly to the numlock button, allowing my to toggle between functions and F keys without holding the fn key?

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming related questions. This would probably get answers from SuperUsers exchange or one of the other similar forums.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no.
But, you can write an autohotkey script for this.

Create a toggle variable in script which will act as On or Off status indicator.
When the status is On, send Fn+F# keystroke instead of just F# when you press it.
(More advanced, you can create a custom OSD for this as well)

I can write the script for you if you cant get it. But, I recommend you try it yourself.
Get authotkey(its free) and start scripting.

I cant guarantee working....because Fn is handled at a little deeper level than standard keys. These might prove handy:
http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=30483
http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=298

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to toggle this feature in your BIOS (aka "Setup Utility").

For more information, see your notebook's [Getting Started Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02824797.pdf).

On page 22, under "Using the keyboard/Using the Action Keys":

> Action keys are customized actions that are assigned to specific keys
>   at the top of the keyboard. The icons on the f1 through f4 and f6
>   through f12 keys represent the action key functions. To use an action
>   key, press and hold this key to activate the assigned function.

Under that description is a "Note":

> The action key feature is enabled at the factory. You can disable this feature in Setup Utility.
>   *If this feature is disabled in Setup Utility, you must press `fn` and an action key to activate the assigned function*.

Additionally, according to your notebook's [Reference Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02820599.pdf):

> To start Setup Utility (BIOS), follow these steps:
>
> 1. Turn on or restart the computer, and then press `esc` while the “Press the ESC key for Startup Menu” message is displayed at the
>      bottom of the screen.
> 2. Press `f10` to enter Setup Utility (BIOS).

[Additional information](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02035108&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN)

Comment: that is kind permanent toggle.....he wants to toggle it on pressing Fn key..moreover, some of the laptops(esp Dell) provide that toggle in windows mobility center(Win + X)..